# Newline while printing in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, newline

I am trying to loop and print a series of characters on a new line. Without `\n` the characters print on the same line:

```
x = 5
y = 0
while x > y:
    for i in range(y+1):
        print("#",end='') 
    y+=1

###############
```

With a `\n` an extra empty line is placed between each row:

```
x = 5
y = 0
while x > y:
    for i in range(y+1):
        print("#",end='') 
    print('\n')
    y+=1
#

##

###

####

#####
```

How can I print so that there isn't an extra empty space, as such?

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the empty string:

```py
print("")
```

Python will add one newline to the end, putting the text on a new line without an empty line.